# Function gives me always a trailing `NULL` back

Tags: r

I have writen this function with several test cases:

```
characterCounter <- function(char1, char2) {
    if(is.null(char1) || is.null(char2)) {
        print("Please check your character sequences!")
        return()
    }

    if(nchar(char1, type = "chars") < nchar(char2, type = "chars") || nchar(char1, type = "chars") <= nchar(char2, type = "chars")) {
        cat(sprintf("%s is smaller or smaller-equal than %s\n", char1 , char2))
        return()
    } else if(nchar(char1, type = "chars") > nchar(char2, type = "chars") || nchar(char1, type = "chars") >= nchar(char2, type = "chars")) {
        cat(sprintf("%s is greater or greater-equal than %s\n", char1 , char2))
        return()
    } else if(nchar(char1, type = "chars") == nchar(char2, type = "chars")) {
        cat(sprintf("%s is equal to %s\n", char1, char2))
        return()
    }
}

#Testcases
(characterCounter("Hello","Hell"))
(characterCounter("Wor","World"))
```

However, after each case I get back:

```
> (characterCounter("Hello","Hell"))
Hello is greater or greater-equal than Hell
NULL
> (characterCounter("Wor","World"))
Wor is smaller or smaller-equal than World
NULL
```

What I do not like on my output is the trailing `NULL`. Why do I get this back?
    (characterCounter(NULL,NULL))

**UPDATE**

```
characterCounter <- function(char1, char2) {
    if(is.null(char1) || is.null(char2)) {
        return(cat("Please check your character sequences!"))
    }

    if(nchar(char1, type = "chars") < nchar(char2, type = "chars") || nchar(char1, type = "chars") <= nchar(char2, type = "chars")) {
        return(cat(sprintf("%s is smaller or smaller-equal than %s\n", char1 , char2)))
    } else if(nchar(char1, type = "chars") > nchar(char2, type = "chars") || nchar(char1, type = "chars") >= nchar(char2, type = "chars")) {
        return(cat(sprintf("%s is greater or greater-equal than %s\n", char1 , char2)))
    } else if(nchar(char1, type = "chars") == nchar(char2, type = "chars")) {
        return(cat(sprintf("%s is equal to %s\n", char1, char2)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `NULL` because that's what you return. Try using `invisible`:

```
f1 = function() {
    cat('smth\n')
    return()
}

f2 = function() {
    cat('smth\n')
    return(invisible())
}

f1()
#smth
#NULL
f2()
#smth
```

Note that if you *force* an output with extra set of parentheses, you'll still get the `NULL`:

```
(f2())
#smth
#NULL
```

Finally, as a general programming note, I think except in one-liners it's very much desired to have a `return` statement in functions and solutions that avoid output by not returning are not that great.

Answer (score 3):

**Every** function in R returns some value. It will be the argument of a `return` call OR a last evaluated statement, if there is no explicit return value.

Consider three functions:

```
f1 <- function() {
  cat("Hello, world!\n")
  return (NULL)
}

f2 <- function() {
  cat("Hello, world!\n")
  NULL
}

f3 <- function() {
  cat("Hello, world!\n")
}
```

When you run them, you get:

```
> f1()
Hello, world!
NULL
> f2()
Hello, world!
NULL
> f3()
Hello, world!
```

Yet the third function also returns `NULL`, as you can easily check by assigning `x <- f3()` and evaluating `x`. Why the difference?

The reason is that some functions return their values **invisibly**, i.e., using `invisible()` function, and these values are not printed when you evaluate the function in the top level. E.g.

```
f4 <- function() {
  cat("hello, world!\n")
  invisible(1)
}
```

will return 1 (as you can check by assigning it's return value to some variable), yet would NOT print 1 when called from the top level. And it turns out that `cat` returns its values invisibly (it's always `NULL`), and hence `f3`'s return value is also invisible.